# Can I access the pictures of the app user?

Tags: ios

I am building a game related with the picture of the client from his album.

I need him to authorize access his album, but can I use his pictures?

For example, imagine a game of finding errors. I use one of his pictures in my app, change 7 objects, and ask him to find the changes.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Unfortunately it being possible is not a coding problem and for that reason this question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The user will be able to give you access to their pictures.  But in terms of identifying objects in the picture and making changes to them, you will have to code in some pretty advanced image processing functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. But would it be block by apple store?

Comment: I think you'll be ok.  Other apps ask the user for their permission to use photos and then manipulate things.  You'll won't be able to permanently overwrite their photos